# ios incomprehensible error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, interface-builder, static-libraries

I'm getting this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LauncherViewController initWithNibName:managedObjectModel:andPartnerKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d52100'
```

when I call the following function :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
   managedObjectModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)mom 
        andPartnerKey:(NSString *)key  {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    if (self) {
        managedObjectModel = mom;
        connected = YES;
        sync_failure = NO;
        partnerKey = key;
    }
    return self;
}
```

with the following parameters :

```
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
NSString *launcherNibName = @"LauncherView";
NSString *key = @"87654321";
```

and of course I checked that [self managedObjectModel] was actually returning a correct value.

N.B. : The LauncherViewController class is built inside a static library.

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling `initWithNibName:managedObjectModel:andPartnerKey:` on an object of type `LauncherViewController` instead of the one you want to call. Please show how you *call* that method.

Comment: LauncherViewController *launcher = [[LauncherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:launcherNibName
                                                                    managedObjectModel:mom
                                                                         andPartnerKey:key];

Answer (score 0):

View controller initialization from Nibs can cause the most confusing errors if you have changed your view controller but forgot to change the Nib and its connections. This might be the issue here. You could easily find out by replacing the Nib with a newly created, blank Nib.

Comment: Seems like xcode screwed up. I set up a new project where I copied/paste the same code using the same static library and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `LauncherViewController` does not have a `initWithNibName:managedObjectModel:andPartnerKey` method. Since you quote an implementation of that method, it seems you simply allocate the wrong class (or you need to call the correct initializer on your `LauncherViewController` class).

Comment: I know, and that's wrong. Because (sorry that I keep repeating myself): Your class LauncherViewController does not have a initWithNibName:managedObjectModel:andPartnerKey method.

Comment: I implemented that method myself.

Comment: I create the launcher object like this :

    LauncherViewController *launcher = [[LauncherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:launcherNibName managedObjectModel:mom andPartnerKey:key];

This is actually working when I do it in a test project with the source code of my static library (I mean without building it and including it in another project).

Comment: (sorry for the mess with the comments)

Comment: If the method didn't exist, xcode would show me a warning telling "instance method ... doesn't exist" right? But this is not the case...

Comment: Seems like xcode screwed up. I set up a new project where I copied/paste the same code using the same static library and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.